# Can't figure out mid-string syntax within For loop

Tags: batch-file

I decided to write a batch script for the first time today, and man, this language is *alien*!

I have files like so:

```
Statement_Jan 2013.pdf
Statement_Feb 2013.pdf
Statement_Mar 2013.pdf
Statement_Apr 2013.pdf
```

and I'm trying to get the month portion:

```
for %%f in (Statement_*.pdf) do (
    echo.%%f:~10,3%
)
```

However the above outputs:

```
Statement_Jan 2013.pdf:~10,3
Statement_Feb 2013.pdf:~10,3
Statement_Mar 2013.pdf:~10,3
Statement_Apr 2013.pdf:~10,3
```

What am I doing wrong with the mid-string syntax?

Comment: You need a temp variable and delayed expansion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured it out.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%f in (Statement_*.pdf) do (
    set filename=%%f
    echo !filename:~10,3!
)
```

Never again, batch scripts. Never again.

Comment: Then why not powershell/perl?

Comment: c'mon. batch scripts are geeky.

Comment: @npocmaka Assembler is even geekier. But I don't recommend using it. :)

Comment: @AndrewCheong Your answer works, but you actually earned my upvote just for saying "Never again, batch scripts. Never again." The only thing I still use batch scripts for are startup/logon scripts that apply to clients that include older versions of Windows. BTW, don't forget to add the `@echo off` at the beginning, or you'll get a heap of garbage dumped on your screen.

Answer (score 4):

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims=_ " %%a in ('dir /B Statement_*.pdf') do (
   echo %%a
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this was useful to learn! Upvoted your answer but in my question I was wondering why my mid-string syntax wasn't working, more than seeking a solution, so I'm going to accept my own answer.